# How to update a single item in a row in SQLite while keeping others same in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using SQLIte in my app.While updating contact,i just want to get a specific item changed while keeping others same e.g if there are 3 items in the row i.e name,number,address I want to update only name while keeping the others 2 same.This the code:

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());
    values.put(KEY_TIME, contact.getTime());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}
```

Please tell me how to do it?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried only adding the one that you want to change to your `ContentValues`?

Comment: @Code-Guru Thanks,i was making that mistake.